# microsoft access control source from a table in another group in a report

Tags: ms-access, report

I am new to Microsoft access, and I am trying to make a report from the data in 2 tables. I am using text boxes and setting the control source to the value from the table in the property sheet. All but one works fine, the one from the other table. The the value pops up with a "Enter Parameter Value" then the name of the main table when I switch to report view. The control source for the text box is "=[Main table]![Due date]" I made it with the little Expression maker in Expression builder.  What am I doing wrong?

I found something close but it did not help me fix it [link](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/why-does-access-want-me-to-enter-a-parameter-value-HA010274377.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

A form/report can only have one Record Source. Create a query that combines the two into a single query, and then use that as the form/report's Record Source.

If you are creating a form and you want the underlying table to be editable, join the tables together and make sure each of them has a primary key.